# Break on Exception .NET 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Seeing some strange behavior in my IDE and thought I'd run it by ya.  I'm running Visual Studio 2010.  When an exception occurs in a function that is unhandled, the program simply exits the function and keeps running.  I'm used to the debugger breaking, popping up the Exception Assistant, and identifying me of the problem.

I have Exception Assistant turned on in Debugger->Options and I have all "Unhandled Exceptions" checked in Debugger->Exceptions.

Suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check "Thrown" as well and it should stop on all exceptions, even those that are caught.